# Opera Mini saved web page location

Tags: opera-mini

I have Opera Mini 7.6.3. I had saved some web pages that I was hoping to transfer to my computer but I can't locate them using File Manager. I have searched both Internal storage and external SD card. Where does Opera store saved web pages?

Comment: You could just set up opera link and install opera in your computer.

Comment: I remember I used to be able to find where sites were stored when saved but now I can't.

Comment: You could also use pushbullet, maybe something changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Opera Mini saves webpages for offline use in a native format it can understand. You won't be able to use the pages even if you found them on your phone.